# Visual studio code python numpy matplotlib

Tags: python

hi I installed matplotlib in vs code on Windows 10 when I installed matplotlib it worked but when I run a simple program I get this import tkinter as tk.py", line 2, in 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Comment: First of all your question is not clear and requires editing. Please revise your question. But based on the error, matplotlib is missing. Have you installed matplotlib? use `pip install matplotlib`

Comment: @m.1.cosacak yes i have do i have to uninstall matplotlib and if so how im using visual studio code

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have Python interpreter in left/bottom of your VS as seen [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/python/tutorial/debug-step-03.png) and terminal opened in VS

If you donot have a working folder for your VS use the followings;

(1) create a folder wherever you want, let say on your desktop named as `myVSworks`

(2) from VS, `File > Open Folder ...`, then seleck `Desktop` by double-click and then select `myVSworks` folder and press `Seleck Folder`.

(3) in your VS terminal perform followings;

`python -m venv myVSvenv`

`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process`

`myVSvenv\Scripts\activate`

`pip install matplotlib`

(4) create a `testme.py` file and add the followings

```
import matplotlib as mplt
print(mplt.__version__)
```

(5) from terminal enter following `python testme.py`

if it print the version of matplotlib that means it works.

**I think the main step here is to use: `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process` See above**

for details check [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial)